# How can I update multiple tables via a trigger when updating a column in one table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have two tables in Oracle Database 10g. I want to update balance in both tables by updating balance in `base_information` table.

I want to use trigger to do this, but I can't understand how could I do it.

Table 1:

```
Create TABLE Base_information
(
  account_no varchar2(40) primary key
    check(REGEXP_LIKE(account_no, '[A-Za-z][0-9]{13}')),
  first_name varchar2(25) unique not null
  last_name varchar2(25), 
  address varchar2(40) not null, 
  contact_no varchar2(15) not null
    check(REGEXP_LIKE(contact_no, '[+][0-9]{13}')), 
  code varchar2(20) , 
  balance double precision, 
  online_account varchar2(15)   
);
```

Table 2:

```
Create TABLE User_table
(
  account_no varchar2(40)
    check(REGEXP_LIKE(account_no, '[A-Za-z][0-9]{13}')),
  balance double precision,
  transfer_to varchar2(40)
    check(REGEXP_LIKE(transfer_to , '[A-Za-z][0-9]{13}')),
  transfered_amount double precision,
  transfer_date Timestamp,
  user_id varchar2(20),
  CONSTRAINT rfk1 foreign key(user_id) references Login_table (user_id),
  CONSTRAINT rfk2 foreign key(account_no) references Base_information(account_no)
);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have the balance in both tables in the first place, when you can just join to get it? Or are you trying to have `user_table` (which represents transactions?) record the balance at the time of each particular transaction? In which case... how would you know which record to update? This sounds like something that should be done as an atomic transaction rather than through a trigger.

Comment: Actually, base information table is the main table where all information of clients is saved and client can transfer balance to another clients . so when client transfer balance I need to update it's balance column in base information and at the same time it's needed to update user table also as client could know the balance related transfer information form the user table.

Comment: Data model and use case aside, I agree with @Alex Poole that this would be best done with two statements in one atomic transaction. Triggers can be great for auditing in some situations, but you really shouldn't be burying business logic in them when it can be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other guys says, its better to do it in two separated statements.
Anyways, if you are still interested in how to do that in that way you could do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER COSO_BT
 BEFORE UPDATE
 ON BASE_INFORMATION REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if :new.balance != :old.balance
      then 
            update USER_TABLE
               set balance = :new.balance
             where account_no = :new.account_no;
    end if;

END;
/
```

As you can see, when you update your base_information table, if the new balance values is different of the old balance value, the balance value in user_table table is updated with the new value in the corresponding account_no record.
Sorry for my english.
Hope this helps!